Error executing PySpark in Docker: "Cannot run program '/usr/bin/python3': No such file or directory"
I am encountering an issue when running PySpark jobs within a Docker container. When I try to execute a basic action like count() or show(), I receive the following error:

24/07/21 17:27:46 INFO ApplicationMaster: Final app status: FAILED, exitCode: 13, (reason: User class threw exception: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/usr/bin/python3": error=2, No such file or directory)

Context
I am using Docker to run a Spark environment with PySpark. The environment variables are configured to use Python 3, and Python is installed at the path /usr/bin/python3. However, Spark seems unable to find Python at this path, resulting in the above error.
Configurations and Checks

Python Path Check
Inside the container, I verified that Python is located at /usr/bin/python3:
ls -l /usr/bin/python3


The file is present and accessible.

spark-defaults.conf Configurations

I added the following lines to the spark-defaults.conf file located at /usr/local/spark/conf/spark-defaults.conf:
`spark.pyspark.python=/usr/bin/python3`

`spark.pyspark.driver.python=/usr/bin/python3`


spark-env.sh Configurations

The spark-env.sh file, located at /usr/local/spark/conf/spark-env.sh, contains:
`export PYSPARK_PYTHON=/usr/bin/python3`
`export PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON=/usr/bin/python3`


Basic Test

I ran the following code to check PySpark functionality:
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession.builder \
    .appName("Test") \
    .getOrCreate()

data = [("Alice", 1), ("Bob", 2)]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ["name", "id"])

df.show()
df.count()


Question
Even after performing these checks and adjustments, the error persists. Can anyone help me identify what might be wrong or suggest other steps to resolve the issue?
Thank you in advance for your assistance!

Show us the output from ls -l /usr/bin/python3.

@JohnGordon lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 9 Jul 21 12:00 /usr/bin/python3 -> python3.8

And does python3.8 exist in that same directory, and if so, what are its permissions?

@JohnGordon Owner (root): Read, write, and execute (rwx)
Group (root): Read and execute (r-x)
Others: Read and execute (r-x)

Well, that's odd.  Are you sure this is the same container where the spark job is running?

If this is in a container, how are you creating the image and the container?  Outside this framework, can you docker run --rm your-image /usr/bin/python3?
